# Can't access function after name changed in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, object, ecmascript-6

There is a function in one of my files in project which I changed it's name and can't access it with new name! still the old name is available to call

I tried deleting node_modules and install it again using `npm i`

there is the code to both files I'm using:

soapCall.js

before:

```
function call(username, password){
    ...
}

module.exports = call
```

after:

```
function checkUser(username, password){
    ...
}

module.exports = checkUser
```

how I imported and used:

app.js

```
const soap = require('../../models/soapCall');
...
soap.checkUser(username, password);
```

it's weired that still I can't access the new function name

I was using name `call` before that and STILL can use `call` function in my app.js file

Comment: Can you share the code, which before changed the name?

Comment: @JothiBasu updated the code to before and after, and of course in app.js file I used ```soap.call```

Comment: have you restarted the server?

Comment: @Ram as I'm using ```nodemon app.js``` to run the server to it restarts after I save every time

Comment: I don't see how you were ever able to call `soap.call` based on your example, you export a function, not an object

Comment: module.exports = { checkUser: checkUser}

Comment: Since you already export a function, calling it with `soap.checkUser` is clearly wrong, you'd have to call it just with `soap(..., ...)`. The problem possibly comes from a fact that `.call` can be called on any function (just like `apply`) thus you were possibly mistakenly calling the function indirectly with `.call`.

Comment: so how can u explain that ```soap.call(...,...)``` worked and STILL works?!?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`call` is already available as a method on the function prototype - [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call). This means `soap` is a function, which is why `call` works, but `checkUser` doesn't.

`soap` is a function because you're exporting a function from your file, and simply renaming it in your main file. If you want to change the name, either change the import name:

```
const checkUser = require("../../models/soapCall");
```

Or export an object and use it as such:

```
module.exports = { checkUser };
// Main file
const soap = require("../../models/soapCall");
soap.checkUser(...);
```

The object method will also allow you to export multiple functions from the one file - you can get these into their own variables with destructuring:

```
module.exports = { checkUser, otherFunc };
// Main file
const { checkUser, otherFunc } = require("../../models/soapCall");
checkUser(...); // Calls checkUser function
otherFunc(...); // Calls otherFunc function
```

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting a function not an Object, so you need to directly call `soap()`.

And about being able to run `call`, it's part of function prototype. So you got confused with [Function.prototype.call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this, as per the comment by @Wiktor Zychla

**soapCall.js**

```
exports.checkUser(username, password){

}
```

**app.js**

```
const soap = require('../../models/soapCall');
soap.checkUser(username, password);
```